# Generate Deubg IPA for iOS in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, ipa

How to generate IPA debug for iOS in react native?
Like in android, every time execute react-native run-android, we can see the debug apk inside apk/debug app-debug.apk. But for iOS I cant find that file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all for iOS you have to generate .ipa not .apk. You have to use xcode to generate release ipa.
Here is process to do that :

1. Open your xcode.
2. Set you build configuration debug to release. To do that on your xcode menu bar click on product > scheme > edit scheme. Now, it will open a dialog, in that dialog there is a tab called 'run' where you can change your build configuration build to release.
   [image: detail image]
3. Now select your run device as 'Generic iOS Device'
4. Then Click on product from menu bar and you can see 'Archive' menu is clickable. Click on 'Archive', now your release ipa is on building.
5. When this process complete a dialog will be displayed when you have an option to export it. Export it wherever you want.

Note, this ipa may only run on registered device only.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I know and I have try to generate release .ipa. My question is, how to generate debug .ipa? is that possbile?
I need to generate debug ipa for testing with Apium

Comment: You means you want to generate an ipa that run on device ?

Comment: I mean, I want to generate debug .ipa or app, not generate relase .ipa, because if I use relase .ipa, if I modify my code, I need to generate again.

Comment: for debug .ipa you have to simple run `react-native run-ios` command

Comment: where I can find the debug .ipa file?

Comment: Sorry, but this command just run you app, not generate the debug ipa. If you really need ipa you have to go through above  whole process, except you have to select build configuration debug instead of release if you want debug ipa/

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your scheme archive to debug mode, and archive your current scheme.

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Archive > Archive > Build Configuration : Debug

Close

Then Archive your build.

Product > Archive